# Can we design an experiment or an intuitive way to demonstrate tidal locking?

Tags: experimental-physics, home-experiment, tidal-effect, intuition

I was explaining the [tidal locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_locking) phenomenon to a friend. First I started with the formation of solar system and how at the beginning the planets were actually like balls of magma-esque rocks. And then how the force of gravity would eventually affect their shape and mass distribution and consequently, moment of inertia.

But I myself wasn't satisfied with this abstract argument and tried to come up with a more intuitive one. So I said: imagine a fresh egg. Its yolk is at its center (almost) and the mass is evenly distributed. Then after a few days, the earth's gravity pulls the yolk down and moves it closer to the shell. This changes its moment of inertia. But I didn't know how to continue and pull a tidal locking explanation out of this. So I said never mind!! There are large-scale forces and objects involved in tidal locking that I cannot scale them down to something more accessible and easier to demonstrate.

Now this has gotten on my nerves. I thought a lot about it and also searched [fruitlessly] quite a lot to find an intuitive, accessible way to understand this phenomenon. We may not be able to demonstrate the effect of gravity on a small scale, but can we use another force that behaves like gravity (e.g. static electricity) to design an experiment for tidal locking?

Answer (score 1):

The tidal force pulls on the tidal bulges on both sides of the globe. This can be mimicked with any pulling force - let's use rubber bands.

Make a disc to represent the earth. Punch a hole in the center and allow a stick to rotate around it, representing the position of the moon. Now punch two holes near the edge of earth disc on opposite sides, representing the tidal bulges. Connect the bulges to the stick outside the disc with rubber bands, representing the tidal force that pulls outwards on both bulges. Now you can see as you rotate the stick, the pulling tidal/rubber band force causes the earth disc to keep its alignment with the moon stick. The apparatus looks something like this:

[image]

This picture sums up the forces that are causing tidal locking. The tidal bulges tend to be pulled into alignment with the external gravitational body.

[image]

Comment: That just shows how tidal _slowing_ works.  At some point there needs to be some built-in residual bulge (i.e., mountain ranges or denser material embedded in the crust) combined with a relative rotation that's slow enough that the soon-to-be-locked body starts oscillating back and forth in rotation, instead of continuing to rotate.  I'm not sure how it's 'officially' defined, but I'd use the phase-locked loop definition: the transition from ever-slowing rotation to one point on the moon oscillating back and forth is "tidal lock", or if you're picky, "ring down".

Comment: @TimWescott This model can illustrate both tidal acceleration and deceleration depending on which way you spin the stick. The tidal bulges get dragged ahead by the gravitational body, and if they pass it, they get dragged back in the opposite direction, resulting in locking. Not sure what you mean about a built-in residual bulge, the bulges are the tides themselves caused by the presence of the moon.

Comment: I'm sorry, the subject is tidal _locking_, but your comment seems to be about plain old _tides_.  Tidal _locking_ is when a body orbiting another body slows its rotation and eventually stops, with one face always pointing to the other body -- like our moon always looking at the Earth, and Mercury always looking at the sun.

Comment: @TimWescott The tides themselves exert torque on the planet, synchronizing the rotational period of the primary and orbital period of the secondary. This model shows how tides naturally synchronize to the orbit of the moon, and it's just a bit of lag to synchronize the planet's rotation with the tidal period. This shows how tides can exert torque on a planet, which is the only thing responsible for tidal locking.

Comment: So if the mechanism is viscous friction, and the torque is a monotonic on $\frac {d\omega}{dt}$, how can an actual _lock_ with position happen?